# What's the answer for log(24) in "cm" that's to base 10.

Tags: calculus

Is the unit of a value affected, when we take the log of the value?....

Example..

Log(24cm) **i.e to base 10**, is the *cm*, affected in some way?....

Although it might be log(24) , .. You know, after getting the final answer, is the unit ***cm*** affected?... 
Is the final value still in **cm** or it is **unitless**.??

Comment: Check [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/13060/what-is-the-logarithm-of-a-kilometer-is-it-a-dimensionless-number)

Comment: The argument of a log (like trig functions or exponentials) should be dimensionless

Comment: *Mr Ripstein* , Thanks, so I still guess "log of a unit value" mustn't be unitless. Reading thoroughly, I got no specific answer as to whether it should or shouldn't but indirectly, it was kinda stated somewhere. Thanks a lot. I even more to explain to my friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logarithm is a function between numbers, it doesn't and can not deal with units. If your equation can't be simplified to cancel the unit by $\log(\ldots \mathrm{cm} ) - \log(\ldots \mathrm{cm})$, then there is a certain mistake in your physical derivation.

Comment: ManDay, it's kinda  Mechanics question, where you take the log of a value and plot it against the other values on the other axes.    Like, the  question might say that plot "L" on the Y-axis and logT on the X-axis. This way, you are expected to indicate their units on the graph eg L/cm and that of logT/(it's unit). So I wanted to know if taking the log of T values which is in "seconds" won't affect the T value.

Comment: Since you'll be considering the same unit for all values on the axis, you can consider them as unit less or just consider $log(24 cm)$ as $log\frac{24cm}{1cm}$ = $log(24)$ and you can carry on.

Comment: What's usually meant in these cases is plotting the graph on a logarithmic **scale**, not the logarithm of the value. Meaning your labels are unevenly spaced but are still labeled with the values **before** taking the logarithm. See also the Wikipedia Article on that subject. For this purpose, you can take the logarithm after just dropping any unit there might be, for a change of the unit would only amount to a vertical shift. Since you are using the original values for the labels, it does not matter.

Comment: Oh, I think I'm getting an answer tho not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks **Free Radical** and **ManDay**. I'm really really grateful. 

Answer (score 1):

The $\log$ function is defined as taking pure numbers as arguments.  You need to divide your $24$ cm by something with dimensions of length before taking the log.  If you just take the $\log$ of the numerical value you get $\log 1$ foot $=0, \log 30.48$ cm $\approx 1.484$.  Many problems have a natural length scale, which is what you use for this.

Comment: I like this example, nice and simple

Comment: Thanks a lot Ross Millikan. Very very much.

Answer (score 0):

$\log(24cm)$ would, by definition of logarithm, be "The number such that, when you raise $10$ to that power, you get $24cm$". How can you raise the (unitless) number $10$ to some power and get the length $24cm$ out as a result? I don't know of such a quantity. Thus I will consider $\log(24cm)$ as undefined.

Comment: Yeah kinda confusing to me too. Thank you Arthur.